# Is the following join sentence valid?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, outer-join

Is this join valid in MySQL:

```
FROM a
JOIN b on a.c = b.c and b.c = 1
```

Well it does work like this but when I use a RIGHT JOIN the **b.c = 1** is ignored.
Why is that?

Comment: Why not just try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't ignored in a `RIGHT JOIN`.

(Conceptually) The Join happens with the filter applied then any non matching rows from `b` get added back in.

So the query

```
SELECT a.c, b.c
FROM   (select 1 AS c
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2) a
       RIGHT JOIN (select 1 AS c
                   UNION ALL
                   select 2 AS c) b
         on a.c = b.c
            and b.c = 1
```

Returns

```
c           c
----------- -----------
1           1
NULL        2
```

You can see that despite the fact both tables have a `2` the additional filter in the `join` clause means that these rows don't get joined. However as it is a `right outer` join the `2` row from the right hand table (`b`) still appears in the results.

**Edit: RE: Question in comments**

> Then how do I `LEFT JOIN` without adding the filtered rows back in? If
>   I use a `WHERE` clause instead the join will be slower because more
>   rows will have to be joined, right?

I don't really understand this question.

You would choose `LEFT` vs `RIGHT` join on the basis of whether you wanted to preserve all rows from the left input or the right input. For a simple 2 table query you can of course use either and just reverse the order of the tables.

Similarly for the issue of whether to put the filter in the `WHERE` clause or the `JOIN` condition. In an `OUTER JOIN` this can change the results (In my example data moving `b.c = 1` to the `WHERE` clause means that only 1 row will be returned not 2)

For the case of `INNER JOIN` it does not matter where the filters are placed but I find it more sensible to put filters concerned with the relationship between the 2 tables in the `JOIN` and all others in the `WHERE`

Comment: Then how do I `LEFT JOIN` without adding the filtered rows back in? If I use a `WHERE` clause instead the join will be slower because more rows will have to be joined, right?

Comment: I'm sorry I meant `RIGHT JOIN` in the comment but I think I get it now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's OK to have extra conditions in the `on` clause that have nothing to do with other tables

Comment: What if the join is a RIGHT JOIN? When I use a RIGHT JOIN the **b.c = 1** part is ignored

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is valid.

However when you use a right join, you will effectively get all the values in the "right" table that doesn't satisfy the join condition in addition to those who do. That's what right join does

Use a where clause to restrict what you pull out of table b in that case.

FROM a
RIGHT JOIN b on a.c = b.c WHERE b.c = 1

Answer (score 0):

Why not write it like this to make it clearer:

```
FROM a
JOIN b on a.c = b.c
WHERE b.c = 1
```

Comment: you should put all your condition on the table "b" on the join clause

Comment: remi - why? Whether you should put a condition in the ON or WHERE clause depends on whether it relates to the logic of the join operation or the logic of the overall query.

Comment: @Hammerite - I assume remi was thinking of the  `RIGHT JOIN` case but it looks as though that was tacked on as an additional question and wasn't there originally.